# iFrame Window Height Cross-Domain (request from host website)

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a website iFramed

```
<iframe name="ifra" src="" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="800"></iframe>
```

The host of the website is trying to manipulate the iFrame height on my website (which is actually a good thing)

how would i allow it to do so?

I get this error in firefox console;

```
Permission denied for <http://idx.themls.com> to get property Window.setIframeHeight
else parent.setIframeHeight('docFrame');
```

Here are the associated lines from the jS file;

```
    function goSetHeight() {
if (parent == window) return;
// arg: id of iframe element this doc is to be loaded into
else parent.setIframeHeight('docFrame');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, this is **not possible**, as it is imposed as a **security restriction**. Imagine if a iframe you included on a page could effectively replace your page if it so desired! However, if you have access to the source of the other site, or, a way to contact the developers of the other site, you can get around this restriction using `postMessage()` on the parent site and the child site, and have the parent set the size of the child based on it's request.